# Combine group_by, ifelse and filter

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to combine group_by, ifelse and filter my code for the example dataframe below. What I would like is the following: 1) Group by x. 2) Check if result > 1. If TRUE, check if month for which result >1 == max(month) for that group. If TRUE, select all rows for that group. All other rows should be discarded (so both in case result <= 1 or (month where result > 1 != max(month)) . So in my example data frame all rows for B should be kept and all rows for A should be discarded.

```
   x month result
1  A     1    0.5
2  A     2    0.6
3  A     3    1.2
4  A     4    1.1
5  A     5    0.9
6  B     1    0.3
7  B     2    0.4
8  B     3    0.5
9  B     4    0.9
10 B     5    1.2


dat <- data.frame(x = c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B"),
                  month = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5),
                  result = c(.5,.6,1.2,1.1,.9,.3,.4,.5,.9,1.2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stay in the `tidyverse` and not venture into base selection, we can easily get there, as well, by just using `any` to check whether any in the group meet your critera:

```
dat %>% 
  group_by(x) %>% 
  filter(any(result > 1 & month == max(month)))

# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   x [1]
  x     month result
  <fct> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 B         1    0.3
2 B         2    0.4
3 B         3    0.5
4 B         4    0.9
5 B         5    1.2
```

Alternatively, sometimes I'll create a "keep" variable to check if I've got the right ones, initially, or to make the code more easily readable by someone looking at my code years later:

```
dat %>% 
   group_by(x) %>% 
   mutate(keep = (result > 1 & month == max(month))) %>% 
   filter(any(keep))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[,  .SD[result[which.max(month)] > 1], x]
#   x month result
#1: B     1    0.3
#2: B     2    0.4
#3: B     3    0.5
#4: B     4    0.9
#5: B     5    1.2
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
   group_by(x) %>%
   filter(result[which.max(month)] > 1)
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   x [1]
#  x     month result
#  <fct> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 B         1    0.3
#2 B         2    0.4
#3 B         3    0.5
#4 B         4    0.9
#5 B         5    1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution With `base R` (without `group_by` or `filter`)

```
res <- Reduce(rbind,lapply(split(dat,dat$x), function(v) {
               if (v$result[which.max(v$month)]>1) v else NULL}))
```

such that

```
> res
   x month result
6  B     1    0.3
7  B     2    0.4
8  B     3    0.5
9  B     4    0.9
10 B     5    1.2
```